# Why does normalizing MNIST images reduce accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, mnist

I am using a basic NN to train and test accuracy on MNIST dataset.

System: i5 8th Gen , GPU - Nvidia 1050Ti

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function,absolute_import,unicode_literals,division
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train,y_train) , (x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
#x_train , y_train = x_train/255.0 , y_train/255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(312,activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(
optimizer='Adamax',
loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test,y_test)
```

When i normalize the images as in the 5th line, the accuracy drops horribly :

```
loss: 10392.0626 - accuracy: 0.0980
```

However when i dont normalize them, It gives :

```
- loss: 0.2409 - accuracy: 0.9420
```

In general , normalizing the data helps the grad descent to converge faster. Why is this huge difference?
What am i missing?

Comment: Why are you dividing the labels by 255?

Comment: As GoodDeeds said, you must not divide the labels by 255. The labels are 0, 1, 2, etc.. That would be wrong. Besides, you forgot to normalize the x_test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
(x_train, y_train) , (x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train , x_test = x_train/255.0 , x_test/255.0
```

You are dividing your labels by 255, so you are not normalizing properly.

Comment: @user9999114 would you mind accepting the solution if you got your answer.here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the same normalization on the training-set and the test-set.
If you use a pre-trained network you should do the same normalization as done by the trainer; here you are missing normalizing the test-set.

```
x_train = x_train/255.0
x_test = x_test/255.0
```

You're welcome.

Comment: Actually, this is not the solution to the author's doubts. The author has not yet made an evaluation on the test set, and the accuracy and loss shown is on the training set.

The problem is that he divides labels by 255, which he should not do.